# jacoco code coverage not working for Android applications

Tags: android, unit-testing, code-coverage, jacoco

My root build.gradle file

```
   buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath "org.jacoco:org.jacoco.core:0.8.0"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-sdk-manager'

allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'jacoco'
    apply plugin: 'com.github.ben-manes.versions'

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }

    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_10
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_10

        // report all Java errors even if the IDE does not
        configure(options) {
            compilerArgs << '-Xlint:all' << '-Xlint:-options'
            deprecation = true
            encoding = 'UTF-8'
        }
    }

    // print errors from test in the terminal
    tasks.withType(Test) {
        testLogging {
            exceptionFormat 'full'
        }
    }
    project.plugins.whenPluginAdded { plugin ->
        if ("com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin".equals(plugin.class.name)) {
            println "Disable pre dexing for module ${project.name}"
            project.android.dexOptions.preDexLibraries = false
        } else if ("com.android.build.gradle.LibraryPlugin".equals(plugin.class.name)) {
            println "Disable pre dexing for module ${project.name}"
            project.android.dexOptions.preDexLibraries = false
        }
    }
}
```

app/build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply from: '../jacoco.gradle'

android {
    compileSdkVersion COMPILE_SDK_VERSION as int
    buildToolsVersion BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "..."
        minSdkVersion MIN_SDK_VERSION as int
        targetSdkVersion TARGET_SDK_VERSION as int
        project.ext.set("archivesBaseName", "..." + versionName)
        multiDexEnabled true

        renderscriptTargetApi RENDERSCRIPT_TARGET_API as int
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
    }

    signingConfigs {
        debugKey {
            ...
        }
        releaseKey {
            ...
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            versionNameSuffix ''
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            zipAlignEnabled true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debugKey
            testCoverageEnabled true
        }
        staging {
            versionNameSuffix ''
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            zipAlignEnabled true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.stagKey
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            matchingFallbacks = ['release']
        }
        release {
            versionNameSuffix ''
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            zipAlignEnabled true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.releaseKey
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
    }
    testOptions {
        animationsDisabled true
        unitTests {
            returnDefaultValues = true
            includeAndroidResources = true
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        lintConfig file('lint.xml')
        abortOnError false
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "3g"
        jumboMode = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    // Espresso
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    // Junit
    testImplementation "junit:junit:${JUNIT_VERSION}"

    //Mockito
    testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.22.0"

    ...
}
```

and jacoco.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

def buildDir = "$project.buildDir"
def taskName = "debug"
def testTaskName = "testDebugUnitTest"

jacoco {
    toolVersion "0.7.7.201606060606"
}

task "${testTaskName}Coverage"(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: ["${testTaskName}", "createDebugCoverageReport"]) {

    group = "Reporting"
    description = "Generate Jacoco coverage reports on the ${testTaskName} build."

    reports {
        xml.enabled = true
        html.enabled = true
        html.destination file("$buildDir/jacoco")
        csv.enabled false
    }

    def coverageSourceDirs = ["src/main/java"]

    def fileFilter = [
            '**/R.class',
            '**/R$*.class',
            '**/*$ViewInjector*.*',
            '**/*$ViewBinder*.*',
            '**/BuildConfig.*',
            '**/Manifest*.*',
            'android/**',
            'com/google/**',
            'com/intellij/**',
            'junit/**',
            'net/**',
            'okhttp/**',
            'org/**',
            'rx/**',
            '**/*_MembersInjector.class',
            '**/Dagger*Component.class', // covers component implementations
            '**/Dagger*Component$Builder.class', // covers component builders
            '**/*Module_*Factory.class'
    ]

    def javaClasses = fileTree(
            dir: "$buildDir/intermediates/app_classes/${taskName}",
            excludes: fileFilter
    )

    classDirectories = files([javaClasses])
    sourceDirectories = files([coverageSourceDirs])
    additionalSourceDirs = files([coverageSourceDirs])
    executionData = fileTree(dir: "$buildDir", includes: [
            "jacoco/testDebugUnitTest.exec"
    ])
}
```

and I am running following command on mac

```
./gradlew clean testDebugUnitTestCoverage
```

When I run this command, it shows message

```
Task ':app:testDebugUnitTestCoverage' is not up-to-date because:
  Output property 'reports.enabledDirectoryReportDestinations.html' file .../app/build/jacoco/index.html has been removed.
  Output property 'reports.enabledDirectoryReportDestinations.html' file .../app/build/jacoco/jacoco-sessions.html has been removed.
  Output property 'reports.enabledDirectoryReportDestinations.html' file .../app/build/jacoco/jacoco-resources has been removed.
[ant:jacocoReport] Loading execution data file .../app/build/jacoco/testDebugUnitTest.exec
[ant:jacocoReport] Writing bundle 'app' with 3040 classes
```

and no coverage gets calculated in folder

`reports/coverage/debug`

however folder

`tests/testDebugUnitTest`

shows passed unit tests data with success.

Comment: Your `jacoco.gradle` clearly states `html.destination file("$buildDir/jacoco")` and your log clearly shows `.../app/build/jacoco/index.html`, so why do you look/expect something in `reports/coverage/debug` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote an article a while ago about jacoco.
https://github.com/uriel-frankel/android-code-coverage/
The jacoco version should change as well:

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco'
jacoco {
   toolVersion = '0.7.5.201505241946'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found solution here.
Just change path of classes directory

```
def javaClasses = fileTree(
            dir: "$buildDir/intermediates/javac/debug",
            excludes: fileFilter
    )
```